# Date time object diff return ambiguous result

Tags: php, datetime

I am facing an interesting problem in php. In my project, for calculating date difference i am using date time object diff method. The problem is, in two script for common case the program return different result. I don't understand what is the reason for the scenario. Here is the code snippet.

```
$DTObj = new DateTime();
$pdate = DateTime::createFromFormat("ymd", 141118);
$diff = $DTObj->diff($pdate);
$dday = $diff->format("%a");
print_r($dday);
```

In one script it return 4 and another script return 5. Note: My system time 2014-11-23. 
I highly appreciate any idea for solving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of **[Date difference only considering year month day](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27344780/67332)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you set the same timeZone for both scripts

Comment: @karim_fci: this is not a timezone issue, and why did you ask this question again?