# Date difference only considering year month day

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to calculate date difference only considering year,month and day in php. Now the program calculate date difference  considering all of the date time object parameter.

```
$DTObj = new DateTime();
$pdate = DateTime::createFromFormat("ymd", 141118);
$diff = $DTObj->diff($pdate);
$dday = $diff->format("%a");
```

How can i achieve that.

Comment: Instead of $DTObj = new DateTime(); use 
$DTObj = date_create(date('Y-m-d'));

Comment: @Ananth: don't do that! Use keyword 'today' when creating DateTime object where you need time 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

Read and try this:

```php
# create DateTime object with time at 00:00:00
$from = new DateTime('today'); 

# create DateTime object from ymd format
# format character ! resets all fields (year, month, ...) to the Unix Epoch and then sets the inputed date
$to = DateTime::createFromFormat('!ymd', '141118');

# calculate difference between $from and $to and return DateInterval object
$diff = $from->diff($to);

# echo difference of total number of days
echo $diff->format('%a');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/231705)</kbd>